# How to save a pandas dataframe into a file when the dataframe is altered?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains two columns.

Then a conditional statement is defined. (*Change the value stored in the second column to 'ON' if the value in the first column is larger or equal to 13.*)

So I would like to save the dataframe into a .csv file if a change has taken place. (based on the comparison)

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'numbers': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
           'switch' : ['OFF', 'OFF', 'OFF', 'OFF', 'OFF']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[df['numbers'] >= 13, 'switch'] = 'ON' 
  
print (df)
```

Output:

```
   numbers switch
0       11    OFF
1       12    OFF
2       13     ON
3       14     ON
4       15     ON
```

The first change is taking place in row 3. That is the point when I would like to save the dataframe first. Then carry on the comparison and save again when the change is detected in row 4, then again in row 5. (The dataframe would be saved and overwritten 3 times.)

If that is too troublesome to implement saving the changed dataframe ONCE in the end when the comparison finished running would suffice.

If the question is not clear enough, please do not hesitate to ask for clarification and I will try my best to provide additional information.

Comment: to_csv is the function you are looking

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use the to_csv to save WHEN the set condition is satisfied?

Comment: You wrote that it was enough to save it at the end right? Also I don't understand what it means to save when the condition is satisfied

Comment: If I save just once in the end I could perhaps store the altered dataframe in a different variable, then compare the new dataframe to the original dataframe, and write the newly created data frame into a csv file if the two data frame is not equal?

Comment: The condition, in this case, would be that if the value stored in the numbers column is larger or equal than 13 then change the value stored in the switch column ("OFF") to "ON". If that makes sense.

Comment: So ideally I would like to save the dataframe immediately after the first "OFF" value was changed to "ON".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the switch values in a vectorized operation, so there is no way to pinpoint a time when the first value is changed. I would thus go for the other idea you suggested, i.e. save the changed dataframe in the end, if there has been a change. You could do that like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'numbers': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        'switch' : ['OFF', 'OFF', 'OFF', 'OFF', 'OFF']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_new = df.copy()
df_new.loc[df_new['numbers'] >= 13, 'switch'] = 'ON' 

if (df_new.switch != df.switch).any():
    df_new.to_csv('data_updated.csv')
```